# Can a droplet of water bounce back when it hits a water surface?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, surface-tension

Is it possible that a droplet of water can bounce from the surface of a volume of water?

Comment: [see for yourself](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pbGz1njqhxU)

Comment: Wow! Amazing video! And that surely answers my question!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you watch extreme slow motion film of a single water droplet falling into other water, usually a completely flat horizontal surface, you see many circular ripples being created, most of the droplet being absorbed by the body of water, but a tiny ( about 5% of original drop ) droplet being formed, and returning back, vertically upwards.

How much of this is the falling droplet I am unsure of, it may me mostly from the target pool.

I suggest a further experiment, where the falling droplet contains an intense dark dye, falling into completely pure water, filming with a high frequency stroboscope or fluorescent exciter, to further determine this.

Comment: How come the last, most little droplet, goes higher than the preceding one? Does the greater mass of the preceding one takes care of that?

Comment: @descheleschilder momentum conservation , less mass higher velocity. (Think of bouncing ball kinematics, momentum conserved between huge mass of wall and tiny mass of ball , carried on liquid)

Comment: But concerning energy the little the fore last ball is losing more to the water than to the little ball.

Comment: @Arif Burhan That would be a nice experiment to measure how much water of the first emerging droplet comes from the first drop! But don´t you need a high-speed camera too?

Comment: @annav But what if the momentum transferred to the water (wich is not a brick wall) by the fore last droplet is the major part of the droplets total momentum, isn´t is possible in that case that the emergent last droplet doesn´t reach the height it does (wich obviously it doesn´t)? I mean, why is such a part of the fore last droplet´s momentum transferred to the water that the last droplet reaches that high?

Comment: One would have to use equations to really see what is happening, the elasticity of the fluid . Qualitatively, a large droplet has large momentum, it transfers it to the liquid and a bounce of the same size droplet would have the same height minus absorption. For the small droplet to go much higher it means it got a larger part of the momentum than its mass by equal distribution.  The large mass coalesced and the tiny bit left got all the momentum by momentum conservation ( instead of zillions of surface  water molecules getting a tiny bit vertical motion as a wave).

Comment: @descheleschilder Observation is the first thing. You've seen that the droplet *does* bounce higher than the original droplet fell from - that's a given thing, confirmed by observation. You *know* that the momentum left (or regained) to the smaller droplet is high enough to make the velocity higher than the impact velocity of the original droplet. No point discussing those - they're simple facts. Now, explaining how exactly the mechanics work that this is the case is a bit trickier, and will likely require more observations - time to get that high-speed camera! :D

Comment: Can the floating of a little droplet of water be compared with the impossibility of pushing two pieces of the same metal against each other and the following non-emergence of one piece of this metal?

Comment: It is the surface tension of the droplet that is stronger than the attractive forces of the rest of the water that makes it keep a shape. On solids it is more complicated as it is crystal structures and energy levels that have to fit for two solids to bind.

Comment: Why isn´t the phenomenon scale independent?

Comment: Ideal fluids have (1) no viscosity, (2) no surface tension .  Real world fluids have both of these, and water, being a highly anomalous fluid [ causes: asymmetric molecule, Hydrogen bonding ]  has these properties at relatively large values.  Many phenomena depend on ratio of surface tension to viscosity , which probably Has dimensions of length ( radius ).

Comment: The video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W7DpP311NxU might interest people in this comment chain. It basically deals with a droplet of water with red dye falling, instead of pure water. It is quite clear that most of the water that composes the first bounce droplet is from the original droplet. Unfortunately, the video is cut before the other bounces take place...

Comment: @anna I´ve read that between the little droplet and the flat surface there's a tiny layer of air, which of course, can´t be there if the droplet is big. I think this is also a big part of the non-scaling property of the system.

Answer (score 23):

Yes, as you can see in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pbGz1njqhxU). As you can see, the droplet will hit the surface, partially *coalesce* (merge) with the bulk, re-emerge as a smaller droplet, bounce 1-3 times, partially coalesce again, re-emerge again as an even smaller droplet and so on. This process is known as **coalescence cascade**. You can find another video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=whYBrLbl1ss). Eventually, the coalescence will be total and the droplet won't re-emerge anymore.

This if the surface is still: but if it is vibrating, another really interesting phenomenon can be observed ([video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=67&v=KZ5ZLPWasrM)). As you can see, in this case the droplets don't coalesce with the bulk, and will stay intact while "jiggling" on the surface until the vibration is switched off.

Comment: So little droplets can roll (or slide) over the water too, according to the second video, where the water is vibrating. Can they also when the water is not vibrating? On a still surface?

Comment: I think the answer is yes, but only for a short period of time. As a matter of fact, you can see at the end of the video that when the vibration is turned off  the droplets won't immediately disappear, but will continue to "jiggle" for a short time. But they will eventually coalesce: if you want to prevent this, you must keep the vibration turned on.

Comment: @valerio92Can you possibly think of any reason why the droplets (after a short time) stop staying on the surface when the vibration is turned off? Or asked the other way round, why they jiggle around so long on the wavy surface when the water vibrates?

Comment: @descheleschilder I found the explanation in this article: http://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.94.177801. Quoting: "As soon as this contact is effective, surface tension leads to a minimization of the interface area and to merging. This coalescence is usually slightly delayed by the need for air to flow out of the intermediate region [...] In this bouncing regime, the air separating the drop from the film is constantly renewed: there is no aging of the system. As a result, the lifetime of these drops appears unlimited." So it  looks like the air layer is the key.

Comment: PS Actually I also found out that someone criticized the air layer explanation and proposed another mechanism: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3208511/